# TyperORM / NestJS - Dynamically create where on search methods

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I have a service that have a lot of models and all of them can be invoked and filtered by the front  end app.
For exemple, 2 of my entities are State and City.

So this is an example of a city:

```
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Afonso Cláudio",
    "state": {
      "id": 8,
      "name": "Espírito Santo",
      "abbreviation": "ES"
    } 
  }
```

All of my services inherit from a AbstractService that implements the find method:

```
  async find(query: FindDto): Promise<ResultDto> {
  try {
      if (!query.take) query.take = 20;

      if (query.page) query.skip = (query.page - 1) * query.take;

      const data = await this.repository.find(query);
      return httpSuccess(Constant.OK, data);
    } catch (error) {
      httpErrorHandling(Constant.CANNOT_RETURN_DATA, error);
    }
  }
```

My `FindDTO` is fairly simple, as shown above:

```
export class FindDto {
  @ApiPropertyOptional()
  @IsNumber()
  @IsOptional()
  page: number;

  @ApiPropertyOptional()
  @IsNumber()
  @IsOptional()
  take: number;

  @Exclude()
  skip: number;

  @Exclude()
  where: any;
}
```

So, part of my structure explained, let's try to explain my problem:
I want to create a method that understands whatever will be sent (that not is page, take and skip) and create a `where` method that will be used in the `repository.find`

For example.
If the request will be: `{{URL}}city?page=1%name=Afonso` I want my example to be returned.
Also, I want to have something that understands if the request demands all of the cities from the state that have the `abbreviation = 'ES'`

I can create code that finds all query entries and makes an object that can be used for the `where` method, like this:

```
const entries = Object.entries(query);

if (query) {
  for (const entry of entries) {
    if (entry[1] !== undefined && !['take', 'page', 'skip'].includes(entry[0])) {
      query.where = { [entry[0]]: entry[1] };
    }
  }
}
```

It works on simple and direct `wheres`, like an `ID = 99`. It will return the City with the ID 99.

But if I need a partial find on a string method? Or find all of the cities that belong to state ID 10, or state with the abbreviation `'PR'`?

I know I can have code that will treat field by field, but my solution is getting bigger and I think this knowledge will be very nice.